# RegEx: Issue parsing forum post body (with quote)

Tags: php, regex

This is usually the type of thing I just hammer away on until I can get it right, however in this case I believe it’s a part of regex which I've never had my head around completely. The greedy vs. non-greedy stuff.

I have this content:

```
[quote=mick-mick topic=33586]
I just gave DayZ an hour of my life. I can never get that back. :/
I had to wait to wait. Slow loads just to get to the server selection screen then once I           chose a server it took another almost 3 minutes to get into the server.

I'll still give H1Z1 a shot for sure. :)
[/quote]

This is a test
```

The regex I’m attempting to use is:

```
/(\[quote=[a-zA-Z0-9]+\](.*)\[\/quote\])?(.*)/m
```

But it’s only matching the quote line.

As you can see I need the username (mick-mick), as well as the topic id, and the content of the quote, and the content following the quote. Also, the quote may not exist in the content at all.

Can you help me on this? What am I missing? I am using `preg_match` in PHP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Final Update:**

To match multiple quotes ***and*** grab all content that isn't even in a quote got a little difficult.  But, [here goes](http://regex101.com/r/vR0fA4):

```
(?:
  \[quote=([a-z0-9\-]+)
  \s*topic=(\d+)\]
  (.*?)
  \[/quote\]
 |
  (.+?)
  (?=\[quote|$)
)
```

This time we use an alternating non-capture group around everything.  We either match a quote (with our capture groups 1, 2, and 3) OR we match 1+ other characters into capture group 4 (this is anything that isn't part of a quote).  The crucial addition here is the positive lookahead (`(?=...)`).  This is a zero-length assertion (meaning it just "checks" but doesn't match) that looks for either `[quote` or the end of the string (`$`) following it.  This is used so that we don't just keep matching into a new quote.

Note: to do a global match in PHP, you'll need to use [`preg_match_all()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php).

---

**Update:**

I updated this to grab content before/after the quote and make the quote optional (by adding an optional non-capturing group: `(?:...)?`).  I also re-read your question and saw that all quotes have a quote/topic (if this isn't the case, you'll need to combine these to expressions a bit..here it is:

```
(.*?)(?:\[quote=([a-z0-9\-]+)\s*topic=(\d+)\](.*)\[/quote\])?(.*)
```

And used like:

```
preg_match('~(.*?)(?:\[quote=([a-z0-9\-]+)\s*topic=(\d+)\](.*)\[/quote\])?(.*)~si', $html, $matches);
$matches[0]; // Full match
$matches[1]; // Before the quote (empty if quote doesn't exist)
$matches[2]; // Quote value: `mick-mick`
$matches[3]; // Topic value: `33586`
$matches[4]; // Quote contents: `I just...`
$matches[5]; // Everything else (entire string is quote doesn't exist)
```

[**Demo**](http://regex101.com/r/wO5hB6)

---

You have some issues in your expression, but it was pretty close.  Here is a cleaned up version:

```
\[quote=([a-z0-9\-]+)\s*(.*?)\](.*)\[/quote\]
```

You can use it like this:

```
preg_match('~\[quote=([a-z0-9\-]+)\s*(.*?)\](.*)\[/quote\]~si', $html, $matches);
$matches[0]; // Full match
$matches[1]; // Quote value: `mick-mick`
$matches[2]; // Quote parameters: `topic=33586`
$matches[3]; // Quote contents: `I just...`
```

[**Demo**](http://regex101.com/r/sW5oQ0)

---

The fundamental issue was you had everything wrapped in `(...)?` and followed by `(.*)`.  This means the first part was optional, couldn't be matched, and then you matched 0+ characters..since `.` does not match new line (unless you use the `s` modifier like in my example), you matched the first line which was the quote.

Also, you used `quote=[a-zA-Z0-9]+` when your quote (`[quote=mick-mick topic=33586]`) had a hyphen, space, and equal sign in it.  Instead, I used `[a-z0-9\-]` (with `i` modifier for case-insensitivity), followed by whitespace (`\s*`) followed by a lazy capture of the rest of your parameters.

Let me know if you have questions or want different functionality.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response and explanation. This does not seem to capture the actual body itself ("This is a test") after the quote? Or am I missing that?

Comment: This still works with a catch-all at the end, so disregard my last comment. I just didn't want to mess up your crafting there. :) As I mentioned in the OP there are times when the quote will not be present at all, but I still need to capture the content. Is that doable here, or should I just match for a quote and route differently?

Comment: Thank you very much! I have learned a lot here. I was unaware of the `(?: )` type group. That is very interesting. Again, thank you very much for the assistance.

Comment: Glad I could help. `(?:...)` is a non-capturing group, works great for nested alternation (`^(?:foo|bar)$` instead of `(^foo$|^bar$)`) and making large chunks of code optional like above.  It is technically the same as `(...)`, just saves you from having unnecessary capture groups.

Comment: Hey Sam, I'm sorry for bothering you again, but quick question. I have instances where a user will quote several people, and respond to each in the same post. So it's this existing use case, but with possible multiple instances. This solution grabs everything between the first and last quote, as expected. Is there anyway to change this to stop at the next `[quote=` beginning, if one exists? (I tried to get this to work, but am not succeeding. Thanks a lot.

Comment: After some time with expressions, it starts to feel like that haha. Cheers!